# How to Implement User Defined Hotkeys

Tags: qt, qml

In my Qt5 QML application I want the user to be able to choose a hotkey for an action. They should be able to click a button called "Set Hotkey", and then whatever keys they press next are recorded and set as a hotkey for the action.

How do I accomplish this in QML?

Comment: Did you look at [Shortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html)? You can give it a string representing a keystroke (e.g. "Ctrl-W") and define what action to take.

Comment: This problem consist of at least 2 subproblems that could be solved separately: capturing a keystroke and applying a shortcut. Note that looking for a tutorial is out of scope on StackOverflow.

Comment: @m7913d okay I'll edit the question to not ask for a tutorial

Comment: Thanks @JarMan, I looked at Shortcut but it doesn't describe how to set it with a user-specified key sequence.

Comment: @m7913d On your advice I have posted the first subproblem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826271/how-to-use-qkeysequence-from-qml?noredirect=1#comment114616088_64826271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example, but you could implement something like this, using an `Item` to record the allowed shortcuts and setting that shortcut in the `Shortcut` QML type.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    RowLayout {
        Button {
            text: "Set Shortcut"
            onClicked: myItem.focus = true;
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: myTextEdit
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: myItem
        focus: false
        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.log("recording shortcut")
            if ((event.key === Qt.Key_A) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier))
            {
                myShortCut.sequence = "Shift+A";
                focus = false;
            }
            if ((event.key === Qt.Key_X) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
            {
                myShortCut.sequence = "Ctrl+X";
                focus = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Shortcut {
        id: myShortCut
        onActivated: myTextEdit.text = "shortcut " + sequence + " pressed!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarod. I had an idea to alleviate the need for mapping keys to strings one by one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862996/353407

Comment: Brillant idea, @Mark Good job! :)